# How to change genymotion installation directory path in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, genymotion

I accidentally selected the wrong folder when Genymotion prompted to select the installation directory.
How do I change it?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Look at Window > Preferences > Genymobile > Genymotion.

You will then be able to modify the previous entry.