# genymotion on eclipse: The system cannot find the file specified Initialize Engine: failed

Tags: eclipse, genymotion

I'm trying to use genymotion on eclipse but It seems i entered the wrong location on setting of the genymotion. Where can I reset the directory of plugins?

Comment: Nevermind the answer was here all along
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18901248/how-to-change-genymotion-installation-directory-path-in-eclipse

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused by a bug that does not let Genymotion plugin work with VirtualBox later than 4.2

Check my answer to this question here:
[Genymotion Initialize Engine: failed in IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19799612/genymotion-initialize-engine-failed-in-intellij/31680463#31680463)